# Is there an umbrella word for cancer treatment?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that there is a noun for cancer as an area of medicine: oncology. But is there a word for things under the umbrella of the art and science of cancer treatment?

I was thinking of something other than "cancer therapy." Something like "oncologics", although that's not actually a word.

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with [**oncology**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/oncology) - defined there as *the branch of medical science dealing with tumors, including the origin, development, **diagnosis**, and **treatment** of malignant neoplasms; the study of cancer.*

Comment: 'Oncological treatment' or 'Oncological therapy'. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24666651

Comment: I think oncology is the word you want. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oncology) says it's *the study **and treatment** of cancer and tumors*.

Comment: I had no idea...'oncotherapy' is an actual word.  http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/oncotherapy

Comment: There is also a journal that distinguishes between cancer research and cancer treatment which it calls 'therapeutic oncology' - http://www.jscholaronline.org/journals/journal-of-cancer-research-and-therapeutic-oncology/jhome.php

Comment: Most of the above words pertain to the treating physician - the oncologist - who may diagnose, study, research, treat and teach about oncology (Cancers of any kind). The best word for the treatment is **oncotherapy**, as in [Combined-Modality **Oncotherapy** With Cyclophosphamide (NSC-26271) and Radiotherapy: Control of Murine Mastocytoma2](http://jnci.oxfordjournals.org/content/57/4/943.abstract) Schenken L L,  JNCI J Natl Cancer Inst (1976) 57 (4):943-949

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with "oncotherapy":

http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/oncotherapy

It's more focused on the actual treatment than "oncology".

Comment: I agree. *Oncology* is too broad; it covers much more than treatment and is more likely interpreted as *cancer research* than treatment.

Comment: Logically is sounds right, but if limited to tumors, it does not address systemic cancers, such as leukemia.

Comment: @medica then a link to a broader definition would be preferable. No sure why you think I resent correction. I don't have enough experience being wrong to have developed an attitude about it.

Comment: @medica I have no idea if it covers nontumorous cancers. That is why I said *if limited ...*. If it covers a wide range of cancers, great, it's a good fit. But I think a better definition of oncotherapy in the answer should reflect that since the linked definition *appears* to be limited to tumors

Comment: @medica Your reference in your comment is great. It's the reference in the *answer* that I have a problem with.

Comment: In my experience, the hospital department that treats cancer is usually called *oncology* (they don't like to use the word *cancer*), but certainly if you want an alternative, this is probably the best alternative.

Answer (score 0):

While it does not seem to cover all therapies that may be utilized, there is *[oncolysis](http://www.cancer.gov/dictionary?CdrID=44612)*

> The lysis (breakdown) of cancer cells. This can be caused by chemical or physical means (for example, strong detergents or high-energy sound waves) or by infection with a strain of virus that can lyse cells. [*National Cancer Institute Dictionary of Cancer Terms*]